# Problema con objetos y funciones - PHP

Tags: php

Tengo una clase `Matriz` con **10 filas** y **10 columnas** con varias funciones. Cuando en otra clase creo un objeto de esa clase e intento usar sus métodos no tengo problema, pero cuando intento crear una función para usar ese objeto me da error.

```
$m = new Matriz();
echo $m->getFilas()." filas\n";//Sin problemas
echo $m->getColumnas()." columnas\n";//Sin problemas
function mostrarMatriz(){
for ($i = 0; $i < $m->getFilas(); $i++){//Undefined variable: m
```

No pongo el resto del bucle porque el problema ya me lo da en la inicialización. No creo que la solución sea crear el objeto dentro de la función porque entonces, se reiniciaría cada vez que llamo a la función.

**EDITO**
Ahora tengo un problema con el constructor de `Matriz` (he modificado el constructor para poder decidir el número de **filas** y *columnas**, pero esa parte funciona bien):

```
private $filas;
private $columnas;
private $matr;
public function __construct($filas, $columnas){
    $matr = array();
    $this->filas = $filas;
    $this->columnas = $columnas;
    for ($i = 0; $i < $filas; $i++){
        for ($j = 0; $j < $columnas; $j++){
            $matr[$i][$j] = new Elemento();
        }
    }
}
```

Por lo visto, no se crea el objeto de la clase `Elemento`, por que cuando intento usar uno de sus métodos devuelve otro error:

```
    public function comprobarValor($fila, $columna){
        return $this->matr[$fila][$columna]->valor();//Uncaught Error: Call to a member function comprobarValor() on null
    }
```

Comment: Añado otra duda

Comment: Tu variable `private $matr;`
 sería más bien: `private $matr ();` y luego en el constructor: `$this->matr=$matr;` lo mismo que has hecho con `$filas... $columnas`. El array se puede declarar solo poniendo () al final de la declaración, en el private únicamente. **Todo lo del for, yo lo pondría fuera del constructor, en un método llamado por ejemplo `getMatriz;`**

Comment: He editado la respuesta con un posible modelo de la clase Matriz.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te comento algunas cosas.

## A. Con respecto al error que tienes en la pregunta

En PHP las funciones pueden recibir [argumentos](http://php.net/manual/es/functions.arguments.php) (variables simples, arreglos, etc):

> **Argumentos de funciones**
>
> Cualquier información puede ser pasada a las funciones mediante la
>   lista de argumentos, la cual es una lista de expresiones delimitadas
>   por comas. Los argumentos son evaluados de izquierda a derecha.

En tu caso, la función necesita **conocer** el argumento con el que va a trabajar. Si el mismo no está declarado dentro de la función y no es una variable del tipo global, entonces tienes que pasárselo cuando llamas la función:

**Función:**

```
function mostrarMatriz($m)
{
   for ($i = 0; $i < $m->getFilas(); $i++)
   {
      //...
   }
}
```

**Llamando a la función:**

```
$m = new Matriz();
mostrarMatriz($m);
```

Con esto tu problema quedaría solucionado.

## B. Pero...

Es posible hacerlo de otra manera. Visto el código, uno se pregunta **¿por qué no crear la función `mostrarMatriz`dentro de la `Clase Matriz()`?**

No sería una mala práctica crear **dentro de la clase** un getter de la matriz completa, de hecho, así lo recomienda la POO (cuando trabajamos con clases). De este modo tu clase Matriz tendría diferentes formas de obtener los datos. Así como tienes un método `getFilas()`, `getColumnas()`, podrías tener un método `getMatriz()` que te devolvería la matriz.

Para ello la función debería tener un return.

**EDIT:**

## Posible Modelo de una Clase Matriz

```
class Matriz 
{
    private $filas;
    private $columnas;

    /* 
        *Constructor con parámetros los cuales deben ser pasados 
        * cuando se crea una instancia de la clase
        * usando por ejemplo: $m = new Matriz ("10", "60");
        * nótese que el tipo de dato puede ser otro que String, indicándolo 
        * debidamente a la clase
    */

    public function __construct($filas, $columnas) 
    {
        $this->filas = $filas;
        $this->columnas = $columnas;
        //... todas las demás variables que formarán parte de la clase y que se reciben en parámetro
        // ... las demás, ejemplo las que devuelven los métodos públicos no necesitan declararse
        // ... aquí sólo las variables que la clase necesita *conocer* para trabajar con ellas
    }

    //En este caso el método no necesita parámetros
    public function getMatriz() 
    {

        for ($i = 0; $i < $this->filas; $i++)
        {
        //... aquí se crea una representación de la matriz en una variable o lo que se quiera
        // es lo que se enviará en el return
        }
        return $variableconcatenadaenelbuclefor
    }


    public function getFilas() 
    {
        return $this->filas;

    }


    public function getColumnas() 
    {
        return $this->columnas;

    }
}
```

Como ves, en la clase los métodos otros que el constructor no reciben ningún parámetro, y podemos acceder a las filas/columnas recibidas en el constructor usando la [pseudo variable `$this`](http://php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.basic.php).

### Ejemplo de uso:

```
//Se pasan los valores al contructor, en este caso los valores filas y columnas
$m = new Matriz ("10", "50");
echo "Filas: ". $m->getFilas();
echo "Columnas: ". $m->getColumnas();
echo "Matriz: ". $m->getMatriz();
```

---

Con esta implementación el código sería más facil de mantener y si tienes que repetir la muestra de matrices desde varios archivos, lo harías con dos líneas de código, en caso contrario, en cada lugar donde necesites mostrarla, tendrías que repetir la función que abre el bucle for.

Answer (score 0):

Eso te ocurre porque la variable `$m` la defines fuera de la función.  Una función "aísla" las variables, por lo que el bloque `for` no puede  "ver" a `$m`.

La solución es pasar `$m` como un parámetro  de la función `mostrarMatriz()`, así :

```
function mostrarMatriz ($m) {
```

El resto del código quedaría igual.